# Episode 5 Spoiler How Meera Reed Was able to kill

Tags: game-of-thrones

Among all the talk being centered around Hodor and Bran's powers (S06E05), one thing seemed to pass in quick succession of time that might would've went unnoticed. My question simply is, sorry for spoiler but,

> We see as white walkers came into the cave and everybody was trying to
>  save bran and themselves, there is one scene in which MEERA REED
>  throws spear like weapon and kills a white walker. I am curious to
>  know what was that weapon and how she was able to kill IT.

AFAIK Only Valyrian Steel and Dragon glass can be used to kill a white walker.

Comment: At the time I assumed that was a spear tipped with dragon glass. I don't recall if there's any shot or mention of it prior to that which indicated the dragon glass tip.

Comment: You seem to be worried about spoilers, but your "AFAIK" combined with your title makes it pretty clear what you're hiding...

Comment: Sadly, you may be spoiling things for people all across StackExchange. Your question hit Hot Network Questions, and the title gets cached there for a while even if you change it. =/

Comment: am I the only one who thinks that the meera was able to kill because she hit the walker.. where as the child of forest before her tries to impale the walker in torso but he catches / stops the spear by grabbing the wooden pole?

Comment: How did you do the "reveal spoiler" section using mathjax?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Her speartip is made of obsidian

Obsidian is, of course, along with Valyrian steel, one of the few things that can kill the White Walkers.

From Season 3 Episode 10:

> JOJEN: Dragonglass.
>
> SAMWELL: We found them at the Fist. Someone buried them a long
> time ago. Someone wanted us to find them.
>
> BRAN: Why? What are they for?
>
> GILLY: Killing white walkers.
>
> MEERA: How do you know that?
>
> GILLY: The walker came
> for my baby. And Sam...
>
> MEERA: But no one's killed a white walker in
> thousands of years.
>
> SAMWELL: Well, I suppose someone had to be the first.
>
> BRAN: Take
> it, Hodor.
>
> SAMWELL: And the archer.

As mentioned in [this article,](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2016/05/game-of-thrones-recap-the-door-nights-king-hodor-dead)  Meera received a bunch of dragonglass from Samwell Tarly all the way back in Season Three. She  has had ample time to incorporate it into her weapons since then.

On the other hand, Meera appears to  pick the spear up from the ground, so it seems more likely that it was built by the Children for the purpose of killing White Walkers.

<sub><sup>Credit to @Telestia for that last point</sup></sub>

Comment: My roomie just said this, but needed more confirmation...anyways thanks

Comment: I figured that it was one that the Children had made, as all of their weapons were made from Dragonglass. Multiple times in the beginning of the scene you see weapon racks with loads of spears on them. If they knew that they would eventually be attacked by the White Walkers, they would have started stockpiling weapons that could hurt them and leave them all around the caves.

Comment: @Telestia - Ahhhhh. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

She used a Dragonglass tipped spear.
But something else I noticed and what maybe nobody else noticed is that Meera also takes a sword with her. But we know they didn't take any swords to that cave and that the Children of the Forest didn't use any steel swords. So that makes tink it was Bloodravens old sword: the valyrian steel sword Dark Sister.

Answer (score -3):

It's not the weapon, because the fairy child itself failingly stabbed the whitewalker... it was Meera, and you see that shock on her face... it's a clue that confirms the twins with Jon Snow theory.

Comment: Jon Snow destroyed the white walker with this sword Longclaw, Valyrian steel sword, in the possession of House Mormont for five centuries. How does it confirm the twin theory?

Comment: "Leaf" as "the fairy child" is called, presumably, stabbed the white walker in the armor, whereas Meera hit it in the throat.